# Extraxcting date using datepart function, but have it returned in text

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently trying to find a way to extract the month from a timestamp field, set up as: yyyy-mm-dd but return the value in either 3 letters (Feb) or the full month (February). It is currently being returned numerically.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The answer is very database-specific. What's the database?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @TheImpaler - I'm using pgAdmin - so PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2):

In PostreSQL, there are several formats to choose from:

```
select 
  to_char(current_timestamp, 'MONTH') as "MONTH",
  to_char(current_timestamp, 'Month') as "Month",
  to_char(current_timestamp, 'MON') as "MON",
  to_char(current_timestamp, 'Mon') as "Mon",
  to_char(current_timestamp, 'mon') as "mon",
  to_char(current_timestamp, 'MM') as "MM";
```

Result:

```
MONTH    Month    MON      Mon      mon      MM
-------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------
JULY     July     JUL      Jul      jul      07
```

Answer (score 0):

`datepart()` is a SQL Server function.  If that is the database you are using, then you can use `datename()`:

```
select datename(month, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

If its SQL Server:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMM')
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017